# Anything faster than iterating ArrayList from the end side?

Tags: java, arraylist, deque

Using this Java code:

```
    // create the items list
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    // ... (add some elements into the list so that it is not empty)

    // iterating ArrayList<Item> from right to left we find the position
    // based on the `if` condition satisfied for an item property
    int pos = 0;
    for (int j = items.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        Item item = items.get(j);
        if (item.property <= 7) {
            pos = j + 1; break;
        }
    }

    // add new item on the found above position
    Item it = new Item();
    if (pos == items.size()) {
        items.add(it);
    } else {
        items.add(pos, it);
    }
```

I'm wodering if this statement `Item item = items.get(j);` will take some extra time for execution because of the `ArrayList` used. For example, imagine we need to add the new item to the end, then by calling `get()` on the items list will iterate it from the left only, which is redundant. I would expect to use `Deque` structure instead of `ArrayList`.

What could you recommend, maybe I'm wrong at all, because new elements can be added in the beginning as well, though the goal is to iterate from the right side to the left.

Comment: I would recommend you to use LinkedList which implements java.util.Deque Check here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `ArrayList`, the operations `get(i)`, iteration and add/remove at the (right) end are cheap (basically O(1) or amortized O(1)). However, adding/removing elements at the other (left) end are very expensive and involve copying the whole backing array each time.

So if you need to add and remove at both ends, be sure to use an `ArrayDeque`. This is basically as cheap as an `ArrayList` for all operations, but supports adding at both ends in a cheap way.

Note that if you only want to add/remove at the beginning of the list, not at the end, you can still use an `ArrayList` and just it "backwards" (so when you want to add something in the beginning, you just add it at the end, and when you want to iterate right-to-left, you actually iterate left-to-right).

Inserting elements with the `add(Object, int)` method is O(n) for both data structures (all elements to the right of the inserted element need to be moved in the array).

An alternative could be to use `LinkedList` (which also implements `Deque`). You just need to be sure that you do not use `get(int)` or any other method where you pass an index as an int, because this is O(n). However, add/remove/insert operations are O(1) at all positions in the list (as long as you already have an iterator pointing to the position). So for the loop in your code, call `.listIterator()` on the list, iterate appropriately and use the `ListIterator.add(Object)` method to insert the element. This would be cheapest solution for your code overall.

***Edit***

I hadn't noticed that `ArrayDeque` doesn't offer the method to insert elements in the middle (although it could, just like `ArrayList`). (Thanks A.H.) So if you really need all these operations (insertion in the beginning, middle and end), use `LinkedList` and `ListIterator`.

Comment: `ArrayDeque` will not work, because the code in the question inserts either in the middle or at the end. `ArrayDeque` can insert _only_ at the end or at the beginning.

Answer (score 9):

`Get` in ArrayList runs in constant time. Proof: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run
>   in constant time.

So don't worry about the `get` performance. The `ArrayList` is not a linked list. I think it is backed up by a plain java array.

Comment: [It is actually backed up by a array.](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html)

Comment: I worry about every millisecond, performance is very demanding, so maybe there is something that is better to use to be able to iterate from the right, because it is more likely that I will add new items in the end of the list, not like in the beginning.

Comment: You coud try sorting the list first (using a comparator on the property value). From memory, it uses a binary sort so it should be reasonably quick. You'd have to weigh the amount of time it takes to iterate through the list against the time it takes to perform the sort

Comment: Yes, by finding a position I sort the list based on the property, I do that on the run.

Answer (score 0):

No, probably not. Your for loop to iterate from right to left, if probably the fastest implementation.

If you were using LinkedList, then the answer would be yes - you should use listIterator() to iterate backwards because .get(i) on LinkedList is slow. ArrayList has listIterator() as well, but there is probably little different between using it and a simple for loop to iterate backwards.

If you are really concerned about every ms, you should take everything people say on this question and benchmarks you read on the internet with a pinch of salt and run lots of load tests and do lots of profiling with VisualVM to inform you where the real performance bottlenecks in your systems are.